# Install Magento in EC2 and Database RDS

Tags: installation, amazon-web-services, aws, amazon

I was Using same EC2 for database and Magento files, and My site got Mysql Issue. So I decided to Use AWS RDS for Mysql

I have created new EC2 ( Amazon Linux HVM SSD ).Installed PHP , Httpd24 ( didn't install MySQL ).Also created AWS RDS. Selected Mysql. Now able to Log in Database Using Mysql Workbench

Don't Know What Should I Do now. Anyone Please Help me What should i do now to Live my Site . Confused about How RDS and EC2 Will Connected and Live my Site

let me know I will have to Install MySql in EC2 Instance Though i have Setup MySql in RDS Instance

Comment: Did you install php5-mysql ?

Comment: I have installed Php and Http24 Only in EC2 and RDS have Mysql When I Created RDS Instance

Comment: php5-mysql is connector of mysql even if you use RDS you will require this php extension to be installed

Comment: @Bhargav I have Installed Php and Httpd24 in EC2 Instance . I will need to Install MySql also in Ec2 Instance

Also When I created New Instance i have selected MySql . Now able to Acees RDS Instance Using Mysql Workbench ..

Now What should i do to Run Magento in Ec2 and RDS Instance

Comment: I will need to Install MySql also in Ec2 Instance ?

When I created New RDS Instance I have selected MySql

Comment: I Tried Using this Code got from AWS Doc

PROMPT> mysql -h <endpoint> -P 3306 -u <mymasteruser> -p

But May be something wrong in Code . MySql Workbench Showing Code Typing Error

Don't i will need this or What i need to Do

Comment: No you wont need to install Mysql only install mysqlconnector of php using command apt-get install php5-mysql

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html

i followed . They given this Code to Connect EC2 to DB Instance RDS

PROMPT> mysql -h <endpoint> -P 3306 -u <mymasteruser> -p

But I am getting 1064 Error when trying to execute this code using MySql Workbench

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your php setup is the same all that really should be involved is changing the MySQL credentials in local.xml to that of the RDS database rather than your ec2 localhost. You would of set up the root user password when setting up the RDS and the host will be assigned after you create it. Of coarse, you will also have to migrate your magento data to the new database if you haven't done that. To do that you can use mysqldump to export your existing database and then MySQL client to import the dumped file.

The other thing to watch our for is make sure your security groups are set up to open mysql traffic (port 3306) into your RDS from your ec2 instance.

Comment: I didn't get you clearly. Unfortunately :(  I am Trying to Install Magento Newly

Let me give me Information What I did . I created EC2 Instance and did

* Install PHP56 , httpd24 ,mysql56,php56-mysqlnd

Created RDS and Selected MySql Machine . Use Same VPC When Launch RDS . Created New Security Group Added MySql

Need to Connect  EC2 with RDS Instance .Following 

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html

But When trying to write code in MySql Workbench getting 1064 error

PROMPT> mysql -h <endpoint> -P 3306 -u <mymasteruser> -p